# Json Exception value going of type java .lang.string cannot be converted to jsonArray

Tags: android, json

I wants to get latitudes and longitudes from server,but i got Json Exception
my class is

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        /*@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress
             dialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Supervisornew.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }*/

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {


                    contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                        String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);




                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
                        contact.put(TAG_LNG, lng);

                        String latitude=contact.get(0);
                        String longitude=contact.get(1);
                        Toast.makeText(Supervisornew.this, latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(Supervisornew.this, longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Supervisornew.this,
                                Mapnew.class);
                        intent.putExtra("hashmap", contact);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                        Intent inten = new Intent(Supervisornew.this,
                                Mapnew.class);
                        inten.putExtra("arraylist", contactList);
                        startActivity(inten);
                        // startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DY   ", "see this");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();*/
```

can anybody tells me hoe to get data from hashmap and show it on map. 
How can we pass hashmap tp another activity and get data here

Comment: thats ur pasing exception, post ur json data

Comment: that error occurs when you are expecting jsonarray as response from your webservice but isn't getting it.Please rephrase your question what you want you want this error to resolve or as you mentioned get data from hashmap and show it.